# Regex to match second line

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to use an expression in WebHarvy (.NET) to match the 2nd line in a paragraph, with a double line break between them

Example

> This is the first line
>
> This is the second line

I have tried using `\n(.*)\n\n` but it returns the empty line break instead of the second line.

Please check https://regex101.com/r/9GjHTM/1

Kindly advise

Thanks

Comment: It is [said](https://www.webharvy.com/articles/regex.html) you can *capture* what you need, so `\n(.+)` seems valid unless you only have CR endings. You may try `(?:\r\n?|\n)(.+)`. Or `^.*(?:\r\n?|\n)(.+)`. If you want to get the result in a match value, use a lookbehind (but only if WebHarvey really runs on .NET regex): `(?<=^.*(?:\r\n?|\n)).+`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Tried all of them but it is returning an empty line instead of the second line with text

Comment: Ok, maybe a limiting quantifier will help (a `.` in .NET regex matches CR, so that might be an issue): `(?:\r\n?|\n){2}(.+)` or `^.*(?:\r\n?|\n){2}(.+)`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor - it still matches the first two line breaks. The expression given by siam works in this case. Really appreciate your help with this :)

Comment: Btw, did you try my regex in WebHarvey or at regex101.com?

Comment: I am sorry, I had tried it on regex101 before and it didn't work as expected, but now that I tried it on WebHarvy, it works perfectly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [WebHarvey regex](https://www.webharvy.com/articles/regex.html), you can capture what you need:

> WebHarvy will extract only those portion(s) of the main text which matches the **`group(s)`** specified in the RegEx string.

So, use

```
(?:\r\n?|\n){2}(.+)
```

The expression matches:

- `(?:\r\n?|\n){2}` - exactly two occurrences (`{2}`) of

  - `\r\n?` - a CR (carriage return) followed by 1 or 0 (=optional) LF (newlines)
  - `|` - or
  - `\n`  - an LF (a newline)
- `(.+)` - Capturing group 1 (the substring matched with this subpattern will be output by WebHarvey)

Comment: Note you may adjust `(?:\r\n?|\n)` to match only the required line break style. If they are `\r\n`, use `(?:\r\n){2}`, if just `\n` use `\n{2}`.

Answer (score 2):

## Answer: \n.*

**You can try this for match second line in Regular Expression (REGEX)**

Regex: `\n.*`

Example:

```js
var regex = /\n.*/;
var str = 
`1st line
2nd line
3rd line`;
document.write(str.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
\n.*?(?:\n\s(?=\w+\S))
```

*see **[demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7nDwTL/2)***

Comment: Hi siam - I had tried your expression on regex101 and it seemed to work fine, but when I try it on webharvy, it returns a blank line. The expression `(?:\r\n?|\n){2}(.+)` as given by Wiktor is just the opposite, doesn't work on regex101 but works fine on WebHarvy. Thanks a lot for your assistance anyway. Much appreciated :)